# Windows Phone Template and Button

Tags: c#, templates, button, windows-phone

I have an issue with a custom control and its template.

I have a control which extends Button, its template was created via Expression Blend 4 and it is available in ressources of App.xaml.

This is template :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="maquette_v0__1_Controles_persos:ImageButton">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="150">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Image x:Name="image1" Source="{TemplateBinding Image}" Height="150"/>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{TemplateBinding PressedImage}" Height="150"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

In a page, I want to add dynamically a custom control.
To do that, I have a grid in my file Xaml "menu_commune" and it is in this grid which I want show my control.

This is the code C# :

```
ImageButton b = new ImageButton();
b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
// bool t = Application.Current.Resources["ImageButtonControlTemplate1"] == null;
ControlTemplate ctemp = (ControlTemplate)    Application.Current.Resources["ImageButtonControlTemplate1"];
b.Template = ctemp;
BitmapImage bi_noPress = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/menu_agenda.png"));
BitmapImage bi_Press = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/menu_agenda_selected.png"));
b.Image = bi_noPress;
b.PressedImage = bi_Press;
menu_commune.Children.Add(b);
```

The problem is nothing is shown.
However, declaration in Xaml runs well.

```
<UC:ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Image="../Images/menu_office-de-tourisme.png" PressedImage="../Images/menu_office-de-tourisme_selected.png" Height="150" Template="{StaticResource ImageButtonControlTemplate1}" Click="tourisme_Click"  />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<UC:ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Image="../Images/menu_office-de-tourisme.png" PressedImage="../Images/menu_office-de-tourisme_selected.png" Height="150" Template="{StaticResource ImageButtonControlTemplate1}" Click="tourisme_Click"  />
```

Here you use `Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"`, and in code you need to use same values. Replace

```
b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
```

for this

```
b.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
```

Hope its help.